# jQuery: Show/hide items using URL hash / fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, fragment-identifier

I have a basic jQuery click function to shows/hides items based on their `data-filter` attribute—not using a plugin like Isotope, just a simple show/hide function— and I'd also like to apply the filter using the **URL hash**, when present, and append an 'active' class to the corresponding filter button.

In the markup, there is a grid of divs with the 'item' class, each of which contain `anchor` elements with the relevant `data-filter`, like so:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#" class="item-anchor" data-filter="apples">Item</a>
</div>
```

In my approach below, I'm trying to get the URL hash, hide all elements whose anchors do not match the hash string, and append the active class to the matching `.filter-button` element:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (hash) {

        $('.item').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.item-anchor').data('filter') !== hash;            
        }).hide();

        $('a.filter-button[href="hash"]').addClass('active');

    }
});
```

I got some assistance from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466096/filter-list-based-on-url-hash-string), but my case is a bit different. Interestingly, the code above is causing *all* the `.item` divs to hide and the `.active` class is not being appended as desired, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any assistance is greatly appreciated, and please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be invoking the filter function, instead of the each function. Additionally, you need to return the Boolean that we should filter based on.  I'm not too sure what your link .active does, but I'm pretty sure you want to filter it by hash.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash) {
        $('.item').filter(function() {
            return $(this).children('.item-anchor').data('filter') !== hash;            
        }).hide();

        $('a.filter-button[href="#'+hash+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks very much @nfn-neil; I had attempted to use the `filter` function at one point, but was not doing so properly (namely, returning the boolean.) One other related question: how might I go about *not* hiding any of the `.item` elements if a hash/fragment value *does not* match that of any of the `data-filters`? I'm realizing an issue with my approach here is that if a hash value is appended to the URL for which there is no matching filter—however unlikely— all items will be hidden... thanks again!